# Get phone name like [[UIDevice currentdevice] name] in js or php

Tags: javascript, php

In objective-c you can get the phone name (e.g My iPhone 5) with `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]`.

I have trying to find out for two days if it is possible to get it from js or php but saw only references to OS version or device model.

Comment: doing it on the browser you can do this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can parse http user agent string by php:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone')) {
echo "You're using iPhone.";
}

if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPod')) {
    echo "You're using iPod.";
}

if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')) {
    echo "You're using iPad.";
}

if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) {
echo "You're using Android device.";
}
```

Find more on David Walsh's blog: [1](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone), [2](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android), [3](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad).

Comment: I know this. I am trying to find out how to get the name of the phone, like 'Andy's iPhone '